# MS Access Crosstab queries drastically increasing database size

Tags: crosstab

I have been working to optimize my database, and was moving all my tables, queries, forms, and... to a new database. When I moved just my tables to the new database, that file size was 14mb.  After adding just 11 crosstab queries, my file size jumped to 28mb after compacting/closing.  I have added queries multiple ways; external data import as well as copying the SQL statement.  Each time it essentially doubles the file size.  I can't tell if this is a problem or not, but it just doesn't seem right that the size would jump like that for just 11 queries.

Comment: What are the 11 queries?

Comment: Hey @ouflak, thank you for the response.  All 11 of those queries are crosstab queries.  Are you looking to see the SQL for each or just curious on the type?